# Does $\bigcup _{j\in\mathbb{N}}A_j=A$

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I'm reading R. Schilling's Measure, Integrals and Martingales and in a proof he makes the following statement.

**"Since $A=\bigcup _{j\in\mathbb{N}}A_j$..."**, is this allways true?

The context:

The object is the verify the third property for a $\sigma$-algebra, that is

$(A_j)_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\subset\mathcal{A}\implies\bigcup _{j=\mathbb{N}}A\in\mathcal{A}$,
where $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra,

for the trace $\sigma$-algebra:

Let $\subset X$ be any set and let $\mathcal{A}$ be som $\sigma$-algebra in $X$.

Then

$\mathcal{A}_{E}:=\{E\cap A: A\in\mathcal{A}\}$

To prove this Schilling starts with:
Let $(B_j)_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\subset \mathcal{A}_{E}$. Then there are $(A_j)_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\subset \mathcal{A}$ such that $B_j=E\cap A_j$. **Since $A=\bigcup _{j\in\mathbb{N}}A_j$..."**

There is no statement about the sequence or definition of $A$.

Thanks in advance!
Alexander

Comment: This $A=\bigcup A_n$ simply means that he defines $A$ to be $\bigcup A_n$, and I guess the next two characters are: $\in \mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I don't see the point though of introducing $A$, and this did confuse me. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{A}_E$ be the trace of $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ on the subspace $E$.  Then for all $(A_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathcal{A}_E$, we have $\bigcup A_i = \bigcup (A_i \cap E) = E \cap \bigcup A_i$, so the trace is closed under countable union.